# Package with Editors having the same RoutingOrder

Tags: docusignapi

In my DocuSign transaction, I have 2 Editors for which they each have a routing order set to "1". I get this error message when I try to create the package :

```
Error calling CreateEnvelope: {
  "errorCode": "CANNOT_ASSIGN_MANAGERS_SAME_ROUTING_ORDER",
  "message": "Multiple Send to Manage Roles (Agent, Editor, Intermediary) cannot be assigned same routing order."
}
```

It works if I assign a different routing order for each Editor. However, what does it change for the DocuSign package ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you have two Editor recipients on your envelope

- Editor One (Routing Order = 1)
- Editor Two (Routing Order = 2)

That means `Editor Two` will only be able to access the envelope after `Editor One` views and  "Completes and Sends" the envelope.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Why such a thing ? Why can't they be able to access the envelope both at the same time ?

Comment: Its by design. DocuSign only allows one person to modify an envelope at any given time.